# Infragistics UltraGrid - Not exporting formulas to Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a very simple test App with an Infragistics `UltraGrid` which I have populated with some currency values.

```cs
UltraDataSource dataSource = new UltraDataSource();
dataSource.Band.Columns.Add("Cost1", typeof(double));
dataSource.Band.Columns.Add("Cost2", typeof(double));
dataSource.Band.Columns.Add("Cost3", typeof(double));

var dataRow = dataSource.Rows.Add();
dataRow["Cost1"] = 10.50;
dataRow["Cost2"] = 12.30;
dataRow["Cost3"] = 14.96;

gridResults.DataSource = dataSource;
gridResults.DataBind();

gridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Format = "C";
gridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[2].Format = "C";
gridResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[3].Format = "C";
```

I actually want o use a custom format string of '$0.00' as my currency may be different in different columns but for simplicity I have stayed with the generic C format string.  I then export the Grid to MS Excel using the `UltraGridExcelExporter` object as follows.

```
UltraGridExcelExporter exporter = new UltraGridExcelExporter();
exporter.ExportFormulas = true;
exporter.Export(gridResults, filename);
```

The display on screen is as I expect with the currency symbol and the value formatted correctly however when I look at the Excel file generated, the values are displayed as standard numeric with no formatting carried over.  I have checked the docs and the default is to export formatting but at the moment I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is handle `UltraGridExcelExporter` [InitializeColumn](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.excelexport%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.excelexport.ultragridexcelexporter%7Einitializecolumn_ev) event. In this event you have access to excel format string of the column as well as to the grid column format string. Check in the  event if the column has a format string and set the excel format string like this:

```
private void UltraGridExcelExporterInitializeColumn(object sender, InitializeColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Column.Format))
    {
        switch (e.FrameworkFormatStr)
        {
            case "C":
                e.ExcelFormatStr = "$#,##0.00";
                break;
            // handle here other format strings you may have
            default:
                e.ExcelFormatStr = e.FrameworkFormatStr;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that not all the format strings in C# are the same as the format strings in Excel.